# gsub string before multiple symbols together in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I am trying to gsub string before multiple symbols in a column together in R. Let me explain with an example

```
data <- data.frame(c("1_a-b","2: b-c","3_c-d"))
colnames(data) <- "ABC"
```

I want the final dataset to look like:

```
data <- data.frame(c("a-b","b-c","c-d"))
colnames(data) <- "ABC"
```

I am doing this:

```
if(any(grepl(":|_", data$ABC))){
      data$ABC <- gsub(".*_", "", data$ABC)
    }
```

I tried using pipe "|" to add another condition like:

```
if(any(grepl(":|_", data$ABC))){
      data$ABC <- gsub(".*_"|".*:", "", data$ABC)
    }
```

But it doesn't work. Is there a way to do it in a step. Also, I have to check if the column has these symbols or not, thus the grepl.

Comment: Maybe `".*[_:]\\s*"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex if you need to remove up to the last `_` or `:`:

```
sub(".*[_:]\\s*", "", data$ABC)
```

Or, if you need to remove up to the first `_` or `:`:

```
sub(".*?[_:]\\s*", "", data$ABC)
```

**Pattern details**:

- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible (`.*` matches 0 or more chars as many as possible)
- `[_:]` - a `_` or `:`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0n5FCS/1) and an [R demo](https://ideone.com/5ThFhZ):

```
data <- data.frame(c("1_a-b","2: b-c","3_c-d"))
colnames(data) <- "ABC"
if(any(grepl(":|_", data$ABC))){
   data$ABC <- sub(".*[_:]\\s*", "", data$ABC)
}
```

Output of `data`:

```
  ABC
1 a-b
2 b-c
3 c-d
```

Comment: Unrelated, but grepl("+", "250K") is giving me true, would you know why?

Comment: @BruceWayne That is how TRE handles undefined regex behavior related to quantifiers at the initial position in the pattern. You can't usually quantify start  of a pattern, it is clearly a user error. TRE is rather lenient in this regard, so you may rely on PCRE - `grepl("+", "",perl=TRUE)` will show you an error.

Comment: What is the alternative to this? except this : "+" %in% "250K"

Comment: As I mentioned, use PCRE.

Comment: @BruceWayne If you just have to check a literal string, why bother with regex? Use `grepl("+", "250K", fixed=TRUE)` that will show `FALSE`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193172/discussion-between-bruce-wayne-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 0):

How about this, using the `stringr` package?

```
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(
    ABC = as.character(ABC),
    new = if_else(
      str_detect(ABC, "\\w\\-\\w"),
      str_extract(ABC, "\\w\\-\\w"),
      ABC
    )
  )

     ABC new
1  1_a-b a-b
2 2: b-c b-c
3  3_c-d c-d
```

Changed to include an if-else statement - missed that you're interested in checking for that sequence.

Comment: I don't know that this really addresses the OP's use-case of using the `_` and `:` as delimiters.

Comment: ".*[_:]\\s*" really works fine and is efficient I believe.